# html and javascript - how to get a button to reset to original state after click

Tags: javascript, html

I am going to use a button I found online:

http://codepen.io/ibrahimjabbari/pen/ulbek

After clicking it, it doesn't reset to the original state, how would I do this?

```
<nav class="ij-effect-2">
```

When you click elsewhere on the page it causes it to reset to original state but I want this done automaticly after being clicked

Comment: What do you mean by "state"?

Comment: so before it is clicked the button has a 3d cube hover effect, after being clicked it remains as if it was being hovered even when the mouse is not hovering over.

Answer (score 0):

Well I might have a solution:

```
function fireClick(node){
    if ( document.createEvent ) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initEvent('click', true, false);
        node.dispatchEvent(evt);    
    } else if( document.createEventObject ) {
        node.fireEvent('onclick') ; 
    } else if (typeof node.onclick == 'function' ) {
        node.onclick(); 
    }
}
```

Using this you can fire a click by calling click on body. With `fireClick(document.body)`. Source: http://www.nonobtrusive.com/2011/11/29/programatically-fire-crossbrowser-click-event-with-javascript/

Comment: could you add this to a codepen.io so I can see it implemented.

Comment: I was unable to get this working but I played a bit with jquery when I lose focus it animates. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjWQxx. You could have a class for a:hover, a:focus and assign or unassign it when needed.

Comment: just looked at it and noticed it works perfectly. What code did you add to each block? could you put them in a pastebin. I just tried the changes you made locally and for some reason I didn't get the same result, i'm guessing I missed a small change.

Comment: I just added the function at the bottom which calls jquery's blur() which unfocuses element and bound it to click event.